# Is it possible to return a custom message in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Graphql always returns:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "errors": []
}
```

Is it possible to also return a custom message?

```
{
    "data": {},
    "errors": [],
    "messages": [] // or with another key
}
```

If not, would tools like GraphiQL or other libs fail if we we would add this as a custom feat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Response-Format) states that a GraphQL response should be a map with a `data` key, as well as an `error` key if any errors were encountered. However, it also provides for an optional third key -- `extensions`:

> The response map may also contain an entry with key extensions. This entry, if set, must have a map as its value. This entry is reserved for implementors to extend the protocol however they see fit, and hence there are no additional restrictions on its contents.
>
> To ensure future changes to the protocol do not break existing servers and clients, the top level response map must not contain any entries other than the three described above.

If you're going to include any additional data in the response, it would therefore be advisable to include it under `extensions`. You can see this done with a number of libraries that implement features like cache control, tracing and cost analysis. If you're using `express-graphql` or `apollo-server` on the backend, both libraries allow you to specifically configure extensions used by your endpoint.